# select a field from a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4.

I have created a LINQ statement to check if 2 input values ie login name and skype name exist in a db table.

Now I would like to extract a third field from the db and dispaly it on screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: provide the code whatever u have tried till now..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

if you give us code what you have tried yet will gives us better understanding. according to my understanding you can use this sample and change according to your needs.

```
var field = from item  in db.xyz
            where item.firstfields == firstinputfields &&  item.secondfields == secondinputfields
 select item.thirdfields;
```